# CakePHP 2.6 DateTime input and user timezone

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

Given a web application that operates in different time-zones, is there a way for CakePHP 2.x dateTime inputs to display the values shown to the user on edit, to be in their timezone.

For eg. If I have a record that's stored in the database that says `appointment_date` (which would be in the UTC timezone), if I, as a user in the timezone `America/Jamaica`, I would want to edit that record with the inputs showing me values in my time-zone, like when I do this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->dateTime('appointment_date'); ?>
```

And of course, lets assume that we'll convert back to UTC time-zone just before save.

Comment: When you say "shown in their timezone" do you mean the default value in the time dropdown shows my local time (rather than UTC) ?

Comment: correct, but note it would be an "existing" value of a record. Imagine editing a field called appointment_date (which was originally saved in the db as UTC)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/antoniovassell/fed29e782be33b7eb5ab 
Which allows for an abstract way of possible dealing with dateTime input timezone conversion, using a custom helper class that extends the FormHelper.

```
public function dateTime($fieldName, $dateFormat = 'DMY', $timeFormat = '12', $attributes = array()) {
        $attributes = parent::value($attributes, $fieldName);
        if (!empty($attributes['value'])) {
            $attributes['value'] = CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $attributes['value']);
        }
        return parent::dateTime($fieldName, $dateFormat, $timeFormat, $attributes);
    }
```

So besides manually converting the form value to user time-zone using the TimeHelper, then setting the value to the input, we could automate this by overriding the Form dateTime function. And whenever we call `echo $this->Form->dateTime('my_field');` it we do this automatically.